# How do I draw a square in the viewport using python and use it to create a plane?

Tags: python, 3d-view, add-on

This is kind of like how the mesh carver draws a square to cut into objects in blender. But I like to do this in edit mode using the 3d cursor as the creation point, of course.

[image: Draw a square]

[image: Plane is added]

Comment: sorry, I don't undertand what do you want...